# `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection` in my node application

Tags: node.js

For learning `Node.js` I follow a course where they use a async/await like this:

```
exports.signup = async (req, res) => {
  const userExists = await userExists.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (userExists) {
    return res.status(403).json({
      error: "Email is taken!"
    });
  } else {
    const user = await new User(req.body);
    await user.save();
    return res.status(200).json({ user });
  }
};
```

But it gives me a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` with crashing the application.

```
(node:10780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise 
which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10780) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero 
exit code.
```

It seems I didn't handle the error part but I did it with my else block, isn't it working like this?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Pretty simple really.  Both of your `await` statements can receive a rejected promise and you aren't handling that.  Surround your whole handle in a try/catch and catch the rejection there.  Also, I can't imagine there's a reason to use `await` in this `await new User(req.body)`.  `await` only does something useful when you await a promise.

Comment: And, this code also shows a database race condition.   One shouldn't test for something existing like this and then creating it as you could have two separate requests, both finding that the user doesn't exist and then both creating one.

Comment: the instructor confused me a lot @jfriend00. If I understood you correctly then I should add a try block and put my `if(...){...}` inside it? and remove the await part before `new User(req.body)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to catch any rejected promise from `await` statements by surrounding it with `try/catch`.

```
exports.signup = async (req, res) => {
   try {
      const userExists = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
      if (userExists) {
        return res.status(403).json({
          error: "Email is taken!"
        });
      } else {
        const user = new User(req.body);
        await user.save();
        return res.status(200).json({ user });
      }
   } catch(e) {
       // some sort of internal error (probably database issue)
       console.log(e);
       res.sendStatus(500);
   }
};
```

This also removes the `await` in `await new User(req.body)` as `await` only does something useful when you `await` a promise and `new User()` is not asynchronous and does not return a promise so there's no reason to use `await` with it.

Note, that to avoid a race condition where two separate requests might both find that the user doesn't exist and both requests may try to create one, you need to make sure that your user email is configured in the database as a unique key so you can never get duplicate users for the same email.  This is a subtlety in server programming that is important to understand to avoid race conditions.

Comment: I tried your code and it give a ReferenceError. `ReferenceError: Cannot access 'userExists' before initialization` @jfriend00

Comment: @NajmunNahar - That appears to be a typo in your question where you show `userExists.findOne()` which is clearly wrong.  It is probably supposed to be `await User.findOne(...)`?  I've edited my answer.

Comment: yes now it works @jfriend00. I have I small question 'Is async/await is similar to promises?' which one is better? And thanks again

Comment: @NajmunNahar - That question tells me you need to learn how `async/await` works because it's just a different syntax for using promises. It uses and requires promises. The choice is whether you use `.then()` or `await` on your promise. That is a programming style choice with no right or wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @jfriend00 said You need to catch any rejected promise from await statements by surrounding it with try/catch. You get `ReferenceError` because of using userExists before it creates. I am pretty sure that it should be User as you named your Schema User `const user = new User(req.body);` Let me know if you have any issue after change the code:

```
exports.signup = async (req, res) => {
   try {
      const userExists = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }); //I changed it to the Schema name
      if (userExists) {
        return res.status(403).json({
          error: "Email is taken!"
        });
      } else {
        const user = new User(req.body);
        await user.save();
        return res.status(200).json({ user });
      }
   } catch(e) {
       // some sort of internal error (probably database issue)
       console.log(e);
       res.sendStatus(500);
   }
};
```

Comment: thanks @emonhossain I saw it. Thanks for your response